# Configure Windows time with high (sub seconds) precision

Tags: .net, windows, datetime

http://time.is/ is constantly reporting my system clock as several seconds off (usually ahead) even if I freshly force synchronization of windows clock with some of the internet time servers (e.g. time.windows.com or time.nist.gov).
This is complicating development of components integrating with remote servers that disconnects me if my timestamps are over second off. Our production HW have specialized HW clock provider with microsecond precision. I do not need anything like that in dev environment, but precision not worse than second is needed.
Is there any public time server or reliable time synchronization utility that can achieve this?

**EDIT1:**
I found and answer to different question that actually also answers my question. https://serverfault.com/a/489016. Among others it mentions:

- Microsoft does not guarantee sub-second accuracies using Windows Time
  (MS mentiones it here http://support.microsoft.com/kb/939322)
- NIST maintains list of third party time software producers here
  http://www.nist.gov/pml/div688/grp40/softwarelist.cfm

Conclusion: for better precision than in order of 1 or two seconds you need to use third party time synchronization service.

Comment: If a synch immediately followed by http://time.is/ wrong then the synch failed, you have a serious clock problem in your HW, item.is is wrong, or nist.gov is wrong.   In a domain you should typically synch with the domain controller.

Comment: @Blam The windows clock dialog provides information about when was the last successful synchronization - so I know synchronization is working fine.
I also do not want to believe that those public time servers are off. How can i verify that my system clock are having issues?

Comment: @downvoter - please provide some feedback on what is wrong with my question (I believe I did quite some research and couldn't found answer and I put my question clear - but I will be really glad to learn from my mistakes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your machine is part of an Active Directory env, then its clock is automatically sync'd to the clock of your AD controller (which is likely sync'd to some other time source).  So you should look to fix the time problem on the AD controller.

If you scroll 2/3 of the  way down on this page: http://www.cites.illinois.edu/network/activedirectory.html it will tell you if  your machine is in an AD domain.

If your machine is not in an AD, you can run

```
w32tm /stripchart /computer:time.windows.com
```

to tell how far out of sync your machine is with a time source (substitute time.windows.com with your time source).

If you want to resync to the time source immediately, run:

```
w32tm /config /syncfromflags:manual /manualpeerlist:time.windows.com    
w32tm /config /update 
w32tm /resync
```

and ofcourse you can re-run "w32tm /stripchart /computer:time.windows.com" to see if it really worked.

Comment: Thanks for helpful commands. Unfortunately MS does not guarantee better than 1 to 2 seconds precision (see my edit). So third party time service is the way to go for me

Comment: I used the approach I described above in a non-AD windows server 2008 R2 environment where our machines' time had to be within 1 second of the clock of another machine that we connected to for the purposes of electronic trading.  Consider giving it a try before bringing in 3rd party software.

Comment: If you decide on 3rd party software, also consider Meinberg http://www.meinbergglobal.com/english/sw/ntp.htm and

Comment: plus1 for mentioning Meinberg as we already use their HW+SW on our prod servers.
I also needed accurate time for purposes of el trading (even though just UAT access from standalone nondomain machine), but second precision achieved by windows time service wasn't enough for me

Answer (score 2):

Standard Windows time service doesn't guarantee precision better than in order of seconds (see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/939322). So third party time synchronization service needs to be used for sub-second precision. List of available providers is maintained by NIST here: http://www.nist.gov/pml/div688/grp40/softwarelist.cfm.

I personally finally chose http://www.timesynctool.com/ (as it is free, reliable and mostly open source - so I can be sure what exactly it's doing)

Answer (score 2):

```
    net stop w32time
    w32tm /config /syncfromflags:manual /manualpeerlist:"0.it.pool.ntp.org 1.it.pool.ntp.org 2.it.pool.ntp.org 3.it.pool.ntp.org"
    net start w32time
    w32tm /config /update
    w32tm /resync /rediscover
```

.BAT Sample File :https://gist.github.com/thedom85/dbeb58627adfb3d5c3af

I also recommend this program :http://www.timesynctool.com/

Answer (score 1):

Windows Server 2016 has made improvements to time accuracy.  1ms accuracy can be achieved in your domain under the right conditions.  See https://aka.ms/WS2016Time for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Just enter the command time if you want the system time.
Like from the command line.

I am just having trouble believing synch immediately followed by time is wrong.

Comment: What exact command are you suggesting (win32tm /resync, net time <srv> or other)?

Comment: What exact commands did you used to get a bad time after a sync

Comment: I used http://time.is/ web page. + I was connecting to the mentioned remote service and comparing my vs theirs timestamps (while reflecting RT latency)

Comment: Post your your code!   You state you know synchronization is working fine.  Post the code that you used to prove that.

Comment: My apology for not mentioning that explicitly enough - I'm using standard windows time service and standard Windows Data and Time GUI for forcing synchronization - it also gives information about last successful synchronization time.
No code involved in synchronization itself. (just retrieving - library I must use is using .net DateTime.UtcNow whcih queries system time)