# Why is time.time() - time.time() = 0.0?

Tags: python, python-3.x, time

```
Python 3.6.4 (v3.6.4:d48eceb, Dec 19 2017, 06:54:40) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
>>> import time
>>> time.time() - time.time()
0.0
```

Why is this the case? From my simple understanding, this function returns the system clock in seconds since the epoch at the exact time of the call. But shouldn't the two calls to time.time() return slightly different floats?

Comment: I've got another result `>>>> time() - time() -1.9073486328125e-06`. Maybe your computer is too fast (:

Comment: Is it 0.0 every run?

Comment: By the way, doing `[time.time() for _ in range(50)]` generates about ~11 unique timestamps on my machine.

Comment: it depends on the time slices the operating system uses. `time.time() - time.time() -> -9.5367431640625e-07`.

Comment: I tried this on Python 2 and got 0.0 result about 1 out of every 3-4 tries.  But I tried 20+ times on Python 3 and never got 0.0.

Comment: @SterlingArcher I performed this: 
`for x in range(100):
    print(time.time() - time.time())`

And it returned 0.0 every time. This is Python 3.6.4, running on Windows 10 64bit.

Comment: Confirm on Win7 64 bits, Python 3.6.0 (from Anaconda). May be is Windows related?

Comment: I am getting `time.time() - time.time()` -> `-9.5367431640625e-07` on my Mac with Python 3.4.5 in general but once in a while it gives me `0.0`

Comment: ```>>> [time.time() - time.time() for i in range(10)]``` ```[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -9.5367431640625e-07, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The resolution of the timer isn't unlimited; it goes up by small amounts periodically. If the two calls are close enough together, you will see a zero value. If you tried a large number of such calls, you would probably find that the difference is zero most of the time, and some number of microseconds the rest of the time, depending on your particular system's speed, hardware details, and kernel implementation.

Comment: Thank you, I believe **close enough together** is what is happening in my case.

Answer (score 3):

Per the [docs on `time.time`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.time):

> ... even though the time is always returned as a floating point number, **not all systems provide time with a better precision than 1 second**.

(my emphasis). For Python3.3+ use [`time.perf_counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.perf_counter) instead.
Or for Python3.2 or older, or for backwards compatibility, use
[`timeit.default_timer`](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/timeit.html#timeit.default_timer), which attempts to pick the most accurate clock for your
system.

Comment: Do you happen to know which systems do not provide better precision that 1 second?

Comment: @JacobLee: I'm not sure if this is what the docs are referring to, but depending on how Windows is configured, it [may only provide 1 second accuracy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/windows-time-service/support-boundary). (That link was found via, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27253216/configure-windows-time-with-high-sub-seconds-precision).)

Comment: Thanks for looking into that. The accuracy of a measured interval t2 - t1 will depend on the stability of the clock and the clock's precision or resolution (the smallest time increment), but not on whether time1 and time2 "true" clock times wrt an authoritative clock. Of course, Python could run on a wide variety of systems, and time.time() depends on the system dependent C program of that name, so it could just be an open-ended caveat.

Answer (score 2):

Not Always, just depends on your cpu scheduling and the clock:

```
n, d = 0, 0.0
while d == 0.0:
     d = time.time() - time.time()
     n += 1
print(n, d)

26096 -0.0010001659393310547
```

Comment: Thank you, I think this function is the best way I could have understood what was happening.

Answer (score 0):

Python's time.time() generates the amount of time since the epoch, measured in thirds of a microsecond, a unit I like to call deltas. This means there are 3 million deltas in every second.

Like a clock only reports time to the nearest second, python will only report time to the nearest delta. So if your code can complete before the time moves onto the next delta, it will report as 0.0!